# Css before and after usage

Tags: html, css, html-lists, blueprint-css

Hi I am trying to insert left and right side images for my UL. The Blueprint css framework is included in my app. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please. Thanks

```
CSS 
  
 

body{
    margin:0;
}

#header {
    height:150px;
    background: url("../images/header_bg.png") repeat-x;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#logo{
    height:100%;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}

#top_nav{
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
}

#navigation{
    height:100%;
    width:55%;
    float:right;
    padding-right:50px;
    text-align: right;
}

#navigation ul:BEFORE{
    background-image: url("../images/header_menu_left.png");
}

#navigation ul:AFTER{
    background-image: url("../images/header_menu_right.png");
}

#navigation li{
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    background: url("../images/header_menu_bg.png");
    height:35px;
    padding-top:10px;   
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:10px; 
}
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/blueprint/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
  <link href="css/blueprint/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
  <link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Site Ismi | Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<!-- Header Div Start -->
<div id="header" class="span-24 last">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <div id="top_nav"></div>
        <div id="menu_nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="first">Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li class="last">Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<!-- Content Div Start -->
<div id="content" class="span-24 last">
   Ruby Content Here
</div>
<!-- Footer Div Start -->
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is exactly?

Comment: Please make your question clearer: what do you want to happen, what is actually happening, how do they differ, are there errors, what have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with it, if I use it in jsFiddle with an image that exists, it shows up in the list items:

http://jsfiddle.net/pZ9Xj/1/

Make sure the images actually exist. Also, make sure you don't use Internet Explorer, which doesn't support :before and :after.

Answer (score 0):

You rather want this:

```
#navigation ul:BEFORE{
    content: url("../images/header_menu_left.png");
}
```

See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) and google for `css :before content` for examples!